# Can I retrieve multiple docs from Mongo by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an array of ids and I want to retrieve all of them at once. Is this possible, can I pass an array of ids somehow and have all of them returned to me? If so, how?

I'm using the node-native driver.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you need to use `$in` operator, that would give you desired result.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: USING WHICH OPERATOR?!?!?!?!?!!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!??!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator you can do something similar to:

```
const ids = ["123", "456","789"]
const items = await db
     .collection("items")
     .find({ "_id": { "$in": ids.map(id => new ObjectId(id)) } })
     .toArray()
```