# Mongo query for several _id

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have to write script which will check last date in mongo.

I have around 3 to 4 ids like

_id=xyz

_id=abc

I have to query all these IDs and need to check their last date.

One more thing is count of these _id increases which is not fix.

So kindly suggest me query for same.

I have tried following query for only one _id

```
db.school.find({_id:/priv-/},{createdDate:1}).sort({createdDate:-1})
```

Comment: again I have to put whole these things in bash script.

Comment: What about db.school.find({_id: {$in: ['abc', 'xyz']}}, {createdDate:1}).sort({createdDate:-1})

Comment: @Schore You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I retrieve multiple docs from Mongo by id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246204/can-i-retrieve-multiple-docs-from-mongo-by-id)